# Can i create PayPal Chained Payment to unregistered in PayPal user as receiver?

Tags: php, android, ruby-on-rails, paypal, payment

I have an application, which needs to send gift payment to unregistered in PayPal users through their email after delay specified by gift sender.

Can i create PayPal Chained Payment to unregistered in PayPal user as receiver?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not use this chained payments.

From the [Developer Guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/):
You can use the `Pay` API to make unilateral payments under limited circumstances. A unilateral payment is a payment that is made to a receiver who does not have a PayPal account. Unilateral payments can be used with simple or parallel payments that are implicit or preapproved. Unilateral payments are not designed to be used with chained payments or payments that require manual approval through the web flow.

When you send a unilateral payment, you send a payment request that includes an email address for a receiver, and this email address is not linked to a registered PayPal account. The receiver receives an email notifying the receiver to create an account and claim the payment.